# Arduino and Intel 8255A-5 interfacing

Tags: arduino, intel

I'm trying to interface an Arduino Mega to an Intel 8255 and it doesn't seem to work, here's my setup:

[image: photo of breadboard]

[image: schematic]

I'm using as LS245 IC to connect 4 LEDs. The CS, RESET pins are connected to GND.
I'm trying to use Port B to send data to switch ON/OFF individual LEDS. My code just sets control register to I/O mode, and port B is set as OUTPUT. Any pointers as to what can be wrong?

My code:

```
#define CS 22
#define RD 23
#define WR 24
#define A_1 27
#define A_0 26
#define RESET 8

char buffer[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} ; 

void setup()
{
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT) ; 
  pinMode(A_0, OUTPUT) ;
  pinMode(A_1, OUTPUT) ; 
  pinMode(WR, OUTPUT) ; 
  pinMode(RD, OUTPUT) ; 
  int i=0, p=0 ;
  for (i=32; i <=39; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT) ; 
  }
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW) ; 
  digitalWrite(WR, LOW) ;  
  digitalWrite(RD, HIGH) ;  
  digitalWrite(A_0, HIGH) ;  
  digitalWrite(A_1, HIGH) ;    
  for (i=32; i <=39; i++)
  {
    if (buffer[p]) 
    {
      digitalWrite(i, HIGH) ; 
    }
    else
   { 
     digitalWrite(i, LOW) ;
   }
    p++ ;  
  }
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(A_0, HIGH) ;  
  digitalWrite(A_1, LOW) ;
  digitalWrite(WR, LOW) ; 
  digitalWrite(RD, HIGH) ;    
  int i=0 ;
  for (i=32; i <= 39; i++)
  {
     digitalWrite(i, HIGH) ;  
  }
  delay(2000) ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that photo is worthless. Please add a proper schematic.

Comment: Just to catch a potential simple mistake, and as its not very clear from the photo, the "supply" rails on the protoboard (the two pin wide strips on either side) usually have a break in them every few of those 5 pin "blocks". In case you were using it as a supply/ground bus, you often see little shorting jumpers every few blocks like in [this pictures](http://www.explorelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1-Power-Rails.png)

Comment: I added schematics: http://cl.ly/image/3l3E0x160t1A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8255 is designed to interface to a microprocessor that has an external memory and I/O bus, and it works very well in that environment.

However, the Arduino does not have an external bus, so you are forced to emulate that bus by bit-banging individual I/O pins, which is slow and painful. Your code needs to generate pulses on the RD, WR, and CS pins, and it isn't currently doing that. You need to take a closer look at the timing diagrams in the 8255 datasheet.

There are better ways to do I/O expansion on Arduino using SPI or I2C. For example, take a look at the [Microchip MCP23S17 and MCP23017 chips](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21952b.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. So proper timming is needed. Any documention how learn to read timming diagrams ?

Comment: It's not timing so much as sequencing.  Also the avr hardware lets you set an entire bytewide port in one operation, so the process need not be as ugly as this program makes it look.